# How many phones can i carry into India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, cellphones, electronic-items

I am spending the summer in Dresden. When I came here, I was carrying my iPhone 5s. Now I bought a new iPhone 6s here in Dresden and I am using it, as well as my older one, which was broken (the front camera doesn't work.) Will there be any trouble at Indira Ghandi International Airport, Delhi, if I carry the phones together in my hand bag?

Please let me know about the details, the procedures, and the problems that might occur and how to avoid them.

Comment: What's your bench press?

Comment: So you're asking how many phones you can carry on a flight to India?